# Pivot Table Using MySQL and Group Conact

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

This is a Question related to my original question

[Pivot Table Using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510657/pivot-table-using-mysql)

Data in the tables are saved like this now

I have two tables Triples and Tags

```
Triples Table has the following Columns

  id  PostID  TagID   Value
   1   1        1     Murder
   2   1        1     Theft
   3   2        2     Knife 
   4   2        2     Gun
```

Tags Table has the following Columns

```
 id   TagName
  1   Incident
  2   Weapon
```

I am trying to write sql to create a Pivot Table with Dynamic Headers

Output should be like this

```
   PostID  Incident              Weapon        
       1   Murder,Theft        
       2                          Knifie,Gun
```

I written a inefficient and partial sql query for this, Any help in writing this sql  appreciated

```
   SET @sql = NULL;
     SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
          CONCAT(
             'max(CASE WHEN TagName = ''',
              TagName,
              ''' THEN p.value END) AS `',
               TagName, '`'
               )
                ) INTO @sql
         FROM tags;


     SET @sql 
        = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW PostTags as SELECT p.postid, p.id, ', @sql, ' 
          from triples p
          left join tags t
            on p.tagid = t.id
            group by p.postid, p.id');

         PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to build two strings, one for the inner rotation to create the columns of `Incident` and `Weapon`, and the second string with use `GROUP_CONCAT` for the outer query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
             'group_concat(',
              TagName,
              ' separator '', '') as `',
               TagName, '`'
               )
    ) 
INTO @sql2
FROM tags;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
             'max(CASE WHEN TagName = ''',
              TagName,
              ''' THEN p.value END) AS `',
               TagName, '`'
               )
    ) 
INTO @sql
FROM tags;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select postid, ', @sql2, '
                   from
                   (
                     SELECT p.postid, p.id, ', @sql, ' 
                     from triples p
                     left join tags t
                      on p.tagid = t.id
                      group by p.postid, p.id
                   ) d
                   group by postid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62afe/8)

This is creating the SQL code:

```
select postId,
  group_concat(incident separator ', ') incident,
  group_concat(Weapon separator ', ') Weapon
from
(
  SELECT p.postid, p.id, 
    max(CASE WHEN TagName = 'Incident' THEN p.value END) AS `Incident`,
    max(CASE WHEN TagName = 'Weapon' THEN p.value END) AS `Weapon` 
  from triples p 
  left join tags t 
    on p.tagid = t.id 
  group by p.postid, p.id
) d
group by postId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62afe/9)

Comment: Thanks a lot bluefeet. It was a quick response.

Comment: Hello Bluefeet,

I have tested your sql query using fiddle demo. it's working
I have updated the data and created a new schema in the below link.
I am unable to resolve the issue. can you help me with this ?
 
       http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42f99/1

Comment: @Swakesh You need backticks around the `TagName` that is used in the `group_concat`. Since your tag is Incident.Type it throws an error, see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42f99/3

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was a quick response ..i agree , i was unable to place those bacticks in the sql.