# Query results depends on result from seperate query

Tags: php, mysqli

What's the most effective way to go about querying the table to output the results as shown?

**Table:**

```
+-----+----------+-----+
| PN  |   date   | QTY |
+-----+----------+-----+
| AB1 | 01/12/14 |  4  |
| AB2 | 01/12/14 |  2  |
| AB3 | 01/12/14 |  7  |
| AB1 | 01/22/14 |  8  |
| AB3 | 01/25/14 |  3  |
| AB5 | 01/25/14 |  9  |
+-----+----------+-----+
```

**Results:**

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
|     | 01/12/14 | 01/22/14 | 01/25/14 |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| AB1 |     4    |     8    |    0     |
| AB2 |     2    |     0    |    3     |
| AB5 |     7    |     0    |    9     |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: `select PN,date,QTY FROM TABLE ORDER by PN, date`

Comment: @Dagon That won't pivot the data as stated in the question. It will simply order the results...

Comment: which can then simply be done in the php output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called pivoting the data. It can be achieved in MySQL with some CASE statements and aggregate functions.

E.G.

```
SELECT PN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date='20141201' THEN qty END) AS day1Qty,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date='20141202' THEN qty END) AS day2Qty
FROM table
GROUP BY PN
```

Of course you'll likely want to do something to dynamically handle the dates that are being aggregated so it isn't just a static list (unless that is what you're after).

See these answers for more info:

[Pivot Table Using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510657/pivot-table-using-mysql)

[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)