# Transpose rows to columns without exact number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with names and scores like this one below:

```
+---------+---------+
| Name    | Score   | 
+---------+---------+
|  Joe    | 1       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Joe    | 4       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Joe    | 2       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Joe    | 5       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Steve  | 4       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Steve  | 2       |  
+---------+---------+
|  Steve  | 1       |  
+---------+---------+
```

Output requirement is to transpose rows to columns so the result table should look like:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Joe    |   1     |    4    |    2    |    5    |  
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Steve  |   4     |    2    |    1    |         |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The problem is that there is no equal number of rows as you can see. For person Joe there are 4 rows and for Steve 3 rows.

Is it possible to transform rows into columns without knowing how much columns it should be in output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510657/pivot-table-using-mysql/15510788#15510788 

check it

Comment: This is too complicated. Inlcudes more than one table, i have to do for one table. It seems that is imossible.

Comment: What about column headers

Comment: It should be also dynamically created. It is easy when number of columns is know, but in this case sometime i can have 5 rows sometimes 9 etc...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to dispense with separate columns and just use `group_concat()`.  This puts the scores in one column with a separator:

```
select name, group_concat(score) as scores
from table t
group by name;
```

A SQL statement cannot have a variable number of output columns.  You need to specify each column in the `select`.  If you have a maximum, say 5, you can enumerate the values and then pivot:

```
select name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then score end) as score_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then score end) as score_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then score end) as score_3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then score end) as score_4,
       max(case when rn = 5 then score end) as score_5
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@name = name, @rn + 1, if (@name := name, 1, 1))) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @name := '') vars
      order by name
     ) t
group by name;
```

If you want a variable number of columns, you can do something similar using dynamic SQL (i.e. a prepared statement).

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this: check it

`nam` is Name
`val` is Score

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN val = ''',
      val,
      ''' THEN val END) AS `',
      (SELECT              ( 
                CASE nam 
                WHEN @curType 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := nam END
              ) + 1 AS rank
    FROM      tab1 p,
              (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
       where p.val=t.val and p.nam=t.nam
), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tab1 t;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT p.nam, ', @sql, ' 
           from tab1 p
           group by p.nam');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad41/8)